# Creating equation for Customer Loyalty Score

Tags: measurement

Goal is to establish a loyalty score for a customers of particular TV Brand.
Listed below are some factors that I think should logically affect the score.

**Features of a Loyalty Score**

- Loyal Customer has a long relationship with brand X (high household age)
- He is a repeat customer ( high lifetime device count)
- His house has majority  brand X devices
- Increase in ratio of brand x to non brand x devices over time
- Replacement Tv tends to be Brand X TV

**Factors boosting the Loyalty Score**

- Replacing TV with another TV from the same brand
- Increase in years of Association with the brand (monoitored by live status of device
- Addition of new TV from Brand X
- Addition of new non TV device from brand X
- User makes a high value purchase

**Factors inhibiting the Loyalty Score**

- Replacing TV with a TV from other Brand
- New non brand X TV appears ( guess work based on brand)
- New non brand X device appears
- Brand X device count decreases
- Brand X TV dies (Lifetime TV count decreases)

We have measurements of the following data

- Age of the customer with the brand
- Number of brand X TVs and non TV devices
- Number of non brand X devices ( we don't know if it is a TV or not but we know the brand name so we can make some assumptions)
- AVL (average purchase value)
- When device dies and gets added

I want to frame a simple formula to calculate the Loyalty score
Loyalty score = Function(Customer_relationship_age_factor, num brand X devices, num non-brand X devices, num brand X TV, num non brand X TV, purchase frequency, new brand X device replacing other brand TV, new Other brand replacing brand X TV, new purchase of brand X and non-brand X TV, high value brand x purchase)

for e.g - loyalty score should fall when a new non-brand x tv is introduced in a house

- How do I converge all these values into a single number? How to establish the relationships
- Values can be normalized. But for changes like appearance of new tv or death of a tv how or how much to adjust the values.
- If weights are to be introduced how to calculate the weights?

What is the best method to address this problem?
It will be helpful if some references or guidelines are provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about it, if you already know these attributes and have some thresholds based on EDA, you can create labels for loyal and non loyal and train a Supervised ML model predicting loyal and non loyal probabilities. This can be used as a score using the feature you mentioned above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).